# HTTP to HTTPS 301 redirection nightmare

Tags: redirect, browser-cache, http-redirect

Thanks for the time. I'll preface by saying I'm not an expert coder by any means but I'll be happy to provide any info as needed.

I'm having a problem that's been going on the past two months thanks to a 301 redirect that I just can't seem to revolve. I help run a news site through WordPress and I had put in years ago a 301 redirect for all HTTPS links to become HTTP after getting complaints about a newsletter plugin rendering links in HTTPS and scaring off readers with warning labels. Little did I know about Google's upcoming shift to HTTPS for Chrome users at the time...

The short version of the story I basically put in a 301 into .htaccess that I can't seem to get rid of now that I converted everything to HTTPS. I followed all of the necessarily instructions and removed the old HTTPS-to-HTTP 301 in the .htaccess file back in September. Yet, months later the old redirect still remains on some of the pages. I can't force all pages to HTTPS since on some pages it creates a redirect loop. The same goes for parts of my sitemap. Therefore, every now and then browsing the site I still have old pages being served via HTTP. I'll attach the code for the .htaccess so you can at least see what's going on there. (I'm excluding the W3TC part to keep it from getting too cumbersome.)

Thanks for any and all suggestions!

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to undo a 301 redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136895/how-to-undo-a-301-redirect)

Comment: The big difference I've seen between this and other threads I've seen (I've certainly looked) is that it's a difference in protocol as opposed to just redirecting from one link to another. So, to the best of my knowledge I can't just redirect from https:// sitename to http:// sitename to https:// www.sitename without the old redirect trying to move me to http:// www.sitename.

Comment: The only way is to wait until the distributed client-side caches expire (no guarantee when this happens) or use a different (sub)domain which is not yet burned.