# Htacess Exeption for api.php

Tags: php, .htaccess

My NodeMCU is saving data to my web server (temperature, humidity, etc) but after i rewrite my server front end and back-end to use symphony framework i am unable to get access to my API file over HTTP even when i have exception written in my .htaccess

MY .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /vasek/home/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.css
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.js
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !api.php
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

i expect to access api.php file in root folder of my server instead get this

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://dev.steelants.cz/vasek/home/api.php">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at dev.steelants.cz Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Comment: The last rule causes this redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirect above is caused by the HTTP to HTTPS redirect which is caused by the second rule. If you don't want to have it, see the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /vasek/home/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.css
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.js
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !api.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !api.php` is not necessary for the first RewriteRule as it is already included in `!-f` (cf. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html; I suppose that the other two rules for `!.css` and `!.js` are also not necessary).  However, you want this exception for the HTTPS redirect.

Btw. you should avoid permanent redirects (cf. [How to undo a 301 redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10136895/3906760)).

Comment: Thank you sou much, can i have following question ?  /n If i remember it correct, if there are RewriteCond next to each other it is same like if i use && in if right ? and any RewriteRule will be apllyed if all Cond are true until there will be next  RewriteCond  after RewriteRule ?